# Cloudfront distributed image shows when entered as regular image, but not as a background image

Tags: html, css, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I want to use a background image on my simple webpage.  It's currently uploaded to S3 and distributed via Cloudfront.

If I include:

`<img src="https://d1z230vfguramf.cloudfront.net/Image_Assets/test-image.png">`

it displays as one would expect.

using:

```
<div style="background-image=url('https://d1z230vfguramf.cloudfront.net/Image_Assets/test-image.png')">
</div>
```

The image is not visible.  Any thoughts as to why this could be happening?

Comment: Is this the actual link of the image you were trying to display? Is the website referencing the image from cloudfront being served from the same bucket and cloudfront distribution?

Comment: I changed the link, but it's the basic idea.  The website is currently just running locally during development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue of CSS than AWS. The way you are using `background-image` is wrong and will not work.

- Wrong => `background-image=url('https://example.com/image.png')`
- Right => `background-image: url('https://example.com/image.png') // use colon`

If this does not work even, then try to add some `height` and `width` to the div to make sure it's not a CSS issue.

```html
<div style="height: 200px;width: 200px; background-image:url('https://d1z230vfguramf.cloudfront.net/Image_Assets/test-image.png');">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So your problem may be solved by either of this two solutions:

1. You are serving a mix of HTTP and HTTPS content which often results to this problem. To solve this, please consider hosting the image on a local server that runs on top of HTTP to make sure that all content is hosted on HTTP so [mixed content](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/what-is-mixed-content/) issue does not take place.
2. You may want to consider configuring your [S3 bucket's CORS configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/enabling-cors-examples.html) to allow specific websites served from other domains to pull your image and display it.